# Rigging model with fur

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, particles, hair

I'm trying to rig the model with hair particles on Blender 3.0, but the hair won't stick to the rigged model while animating, is there any solution for me to fix the problem?
([[image: Thiki Hairs]]

Answer (score 3):

Check if Armature modifier is before particles in modifier list.

[image]

And also check if **use modifier stack** is enabled:

[image]